# Add to set elements of a splitted string

Tags: python

I'm receiving values as strings, separated by comma.
Example:

```
alpha, gane, delta
delta, opsirom, nado
```

I want to obtain a list/set of uniques values, sorted. I'm trying to use a set for uniquenes:

```
app = set()
for r in result:
            app = app | set(r.split[","])
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: ```r.split(",")```, not ```r.split[","]```

Comment: Multiple strings (lines) or just one?  Is the delimiter use consistent (', ', comma followed by one space)?

Comment: @hpauj multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a mix between `split` and `replace` if I'm understand your input correctly and `set` for uniqueness as you stated:

```
value_1 = "alpha, gane, delta, alpha"
aux_1 = value_1.replace(" ","").split(",")
a = list(set(aux_1))
print(a)
#Another list formatted as string arrives:
value_2 = "alpha, beta, omega, beta"
aux_2 = value_2.replace(" ","").split(",")

#Option 1:
a += list(set(aux_2))
a = list(set(a))
print(a)

#Option 2:
for i in aux_2:
    if i in a:
        pass
    else:
        a.append(i)
print(a)
```

Output for both cases:

```
['delta', 'gane', 'omega', 'beta', 'alpha']
```

After you receive another string you can add the values to the full list, in this case `a` and use `set()` again to eliminate further duplicates. Or check for each individual value if the the value in the string is `in` the full list and append it if it's not, or skip if it already exists in the full list.

Answer (score 0):

as well as you can use below code,

```
splited_inputs = inputs.split(',')
unique_values = list(dict.fromkeys(splited_inputs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = "alpha, gane, delta, delta, opsirom, nado"   

unique_values = list(set(s.rsplit(', ')))
print(unique_values)
```

outputs:

```
['opsirom', 'delta', 'alpha', 'gane', 'nado']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not too far off.  The immediate problem was the use of `[]` instead of `()` for the `split` function call.

```
In [151]: alist = """alpha, gane, delta 
     ...: delta, opsirom, nado""".splitlines()                                                   
In [152]: alist                                                                                  
Out[152]: ['alpha, gane, delta', 'delta, opsirom, nado']
In [153]: aset = set()                                                                           
In [154]: for astr in alist: 
     ...:     aset |= set(astr.split(', ')) 
     ...:                                                                                        
In [155]: aset                                                                                   
Out[155]: {'alpha', 'delta', 'gane', 'nado', 'opsirom'}
```

The use `|` to join sets is fine; I used the `\=` version.  The split delimiter needed to be tweaked to avoid having both 'delta' and ' delta' in result.  Otherwise you might need to apply `strip` to each string.  `@Victor` got this part right.